# Average solutions in infinite search tree

Tags: probability-theory, search-trees

I have the following problem:

> Consider a balanced infinite search tree with branching number $κ$. Consider a
>   search problem with solutions which may be located at any node of the tree.
>   The search will not be terminated once a solution is found. The only information about solutions is that if you check a node at level $l$ the likelihood of finding a solution is $p^l$ (and $0 ≤ p ≤ 1$). 
>   a) Using breadth-first search, how many solutions will you find using an infinitely large tree? 
>   b) Using depth-first search?

I know the average number of solutions on a level $l$ is $l^k p^l$, and that I need to use geometric sequences to sum through the tree but I'm not sure how to proceed. How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Have you tried working through some small examples, to get a feeling for the patterns?

Comment: This is a weird question. Why you would use a completely meaningless "data structure" and "algorithm" to make people compute some expected values, I don't know.